# How to stop IntelliJ Scala plugin indenting blocks

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

On IntelliJ 9.0.2 with the latest Scala plugin, the problem is that the code formatter turns this:

```
  object Test
  {
    def main (args: Array[String])
    {
      if (...)
      {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

into this:

```
  object Test
  {
    def main (args: Array[String])
      {
        if (...)
          {
            ...
          }
      }
  }
```

i.e. it's indenting the blocks, and I've done my best to tell it not to in the preferences.

It's a small thing, but is slowing driving me batty :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a bug, I've lodged an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-2066).

It's more common in Scala code to leave the brace on the previous line. This is formatted correctly by IntelliJ. But to each his own...